# Marker listener in a loop in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I have a bunch of markers in an `index page` which I create and register listeners to them in a loop. I click on one of those markers and it takes me to `next page` where I have an `anchor button` that needs to know which marker initiated the action. I am having a following scenario step wise:

- Click marker 1 `//outputs a correct id 1 in console`
- Takes me to next page    `//outputs a correct id 1 in console on clicking anchor`
- Come back to index page and click on marker 2 `//outputs a correct id 2 in console`
- Takes me to next page `//outputs both ids 1 and 2 in console on clicking anchor`

The last step is where the problem is where I just want `id 2`. In fact if I repeat the process the third time, I get all the ids 1, 2 and 3 while I want just the `id 3` in this case.

My code:

```
$.each(otherLocations, function(index, value){
  var markerOtherLocations = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude),
    map: map,
    title: value.name+" "+value.distance,
    icon: iconImage,
    labelContent: value.name+" "+value.distance,
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 0),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.60}
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(markerOtherLocations, 'click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#detail-page", { transition: "flip"} );
    console.log(value.localurl);//Outputs correct url

    $("#ref").on("click", function(){  //The problem is in this anchor click
      console.log(value.localurl);//Outputs the current as well as all the previous urls
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time when you click the markerOtherLocations, it will register a brand new `onclick` event callback for `#ref` which causes the problem. Remember an event can be registered by many callbacks. Consider the code below:

```
$("#ref").on("click", function(){  
  console.log('do function A');//register A first
});

$("#ref").on("click", function(){ 
  console.log('do function B');//register B later, which won't be overridden.
});

//If you click #ref then, it'll output A and B, following the registered sequence before.
```

So in my opinion, your code could be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerOtherLocations, 'click', function() {
  $.mobile.changePage("#detail-page", { transition: "flip"} );
  console.log(value.localurl);//Outputs correct url
  $("#ref").data('origin',value.localurl);
});

$("#ref").on("click", function(){ // register once 
  console.log($(this).data('origin'));
});
```

Comment: Yes, the way you suggested worked. Now I have the `handle` of the latest marker being clicked. However since it was inside the `each` loop I was getting the same `handle` multiple times. I put it outside the loop and it's perfect now. But again the catch is, since I also have a refresh function in the `index page` as a result the whole script runs again when I refresh. Due to this I again get the correct `handle` multiple times. But that doesn't matter. At least I am getting the correct one. Many thanks...:-)